# C# Unity - NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am getting the following error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Burrow.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Angry Birds Style/Scripts/Burrow.cs:16)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

When I try to run this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Burrow : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown() {
        if (!GameObject.Find("Projectile").GetComponent<ProjectileDragging>().launch) {
        GameObject.Find("Projectile").GetComponent<ProjectileDragging>().burrow = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This script is attempting to reference variables from a script from a separate object in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if at all possible, don't use `GameObject.Find()`, it's terribly inefficient.

Secondly it's likely that the game object isn't being found, you should check that it is not null first, and then do your operations.